Handling XSS vulnerabilities in springboot for uploaded multipart file
I have a situation in my hand in which i have to check for XSS-vulnerability in spring boot for uploaded multipart file.
Is there implementation or logic which you guys know. Would be of great help if someone share.
Thank you.
